# Is there any difference between {:x => 1} and {:x => 1, :y => nil} in ruby?

Tags: ruby, null

**Edit:**

There are tons of great answers here till I do not know which to select as the "answer". Based on a comment suggestion, this question should be marked as "off topic". Hence, I'm sorry but I will not choosing an answer and I shall leave this here in case someone else has the same question I have.

---

Is there a difference between:

(1)

```
a = {
  :x => 1
}
```

And

(2)

```
b = {
  :x => 1,
  :y => nil
}
```

Given that for (1), `a[:y] returns nil`
And for (2), `b[:y] returns nil` as well

---

The only difference I see is that when I output:

(1)

```
{
  :x => 1
}
```

And (2)

```
{
  :x => 1
  :y => nil
}
```

Comment: If a hash `h` may or may not have a key `:y` and one wants to obtain the `:y`'s value, if the key is present, one should write `if h.key?(:y); x = h[:y]; ....; else ...; end`, so there's an obvious difference in the two cases. One should never use `h[:y].nil?` to test if a hash has a given key; always use `h.key?(:y)`. The former is safer and reads better. I think it's best, however, to design hashes that do not have `nil` values.

Comment: `{x: 1} == {x: 1, y: nil} #  => false`

Comment: `{x: 1}.count == 1`, `{x: 1, y: nil}.count == 2`. `{x: 1}.values == [1]`, `{x: 1, y: nil}.values == [1, nil]`. `{x: 1}.key(nil) == nil`, `{x: 1, y: nil}.key(nil) == :y`.....

Comment: Yes, it's true that `a[:y] == b[:y] == nil`, but that's the **only** similarity between the two hashes. I can't think of a single other way that the hashes behave the same.

Comment: @TomLord: `{x: 1}.compact == {x: 1, y: nil}.compact #=> true`

Comment: As Tom Lord wrote in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195486/is-there-any-difference-between-x-1-and-x-1-y-nil-in-ruby#comment100905466_57195542), this is a strange question to ask, since the two hashes behave *completely different in almost every way*, so asking for a list of differences is going to be a veeeeeeeeeeeery long list. It would be better if you could explain the *actual problem* you are having.

Comment: `{x: 1}.keys # => [:x]` But `{x: 1, y: nil}.keys # => [:x, :y]`

Comment: @JörgWMittag There is no issue. It was just something I came across and was trying to wrap my head around. And it seems that there are so many good answers here that I do not know which to choose as the right answer..

Comment: @Kiong: That is the problem with list questions, and is the reason why list questions are off-topic. Questions must have a single, objectively correct, verifiable answer. "Give me a list of all the things" does *by definition* not have a single answer, it has an infinite list of answers.

Comment: Then, I guess this question should be marked as "off-topic" then. *sorry guys & thanks for taking the time to answer this question!

Answer (score 5):

There are several differences. Let me describe two, so you know where to look:

[`Hash#fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) raises error (or calls a block if it's provided) if key is not present:

```
a.fetch(:y)
# >> KeyError: key not found: :y
> a.fetch(:y){ "100" }
# => "100"
b.fetch(:y)
# => nil
b.fetch(:y){ "100" }
# => nil
```

[`Hash#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (and all other iterators) takes the key with `nil` value into account:

```
a.map{|k, v| [k, v]}
# => [[:x, 1]]
b.map{|k, v| [k, v]}
# => [[:x, 1], [:y, nil]]
```

Comment: The two objects behave differently in almost every way; it's actually much harder to name similarities!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the hash has a different number of pairs. `hsh.keys` will return `[:x, :y]`

Answer (score 0):

Both hashes return nil value for `:x` and `:y` keys because they are configured to return nil when no key is found. This is the default behaviour in Ruby.

However you can change that behaviour when initializing your hash

```rb
c = Hash.new("foo")
c[:x] = 1
c[:x]
# => 1
c[:y]
# => "foo"
```